# in Bootstrap 4, textbox form-control width is not working. the textbox does not appear in full-width. I'm using asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, textbox, bootstrap-4, form-control

[image]

```html
     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 my-3">
                            <div class="card card-outline-secondary">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <form class="form" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label form-control-label">First Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Last name</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Middle name</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Name Extension</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Date of Birth</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="date" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Gender</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label"></label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Cancel">
                                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div><!-- card body -->
                            </div> <!-- card-outline -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I want to make the textbox appear in full-width. I did my research and found out that the width is in default to appear in full-width but in my work it appears in a fixed size.

Comment: Did you check the container? it is there? <div class="container">

Answer (score 1):

Your `<form>` is nested inside the `card`;
Your `card` is nested inside `col-md-6` of the `row`;

Hence on `media(min-width: 992px)`, your `form-control`s will only get

1/2 * 9/12 = 37.5% of the full width.

Your form labels and inputs are already using full width of the **card**. The problem is, the card is not using full width of the container.

To fix that, you can either remove `<div class="row">` and `<div class="col-md-6 my-3">` completely, or just change `<div class="col-md-6 my-3">` to `<div class="col-md-12 my-3">`

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/86873/

Comment: yes, i want to use the remaining width of the card. I used col-lg-3 on the label, and so I used the col-lg-9 to the div of the textbox.

Comment: I guess you still don't get it. The card is not in full width even you used col-lg-9 to the div of the textbox. The card is wrapped in col-md-6. If you want the card to take up the full width, just take out the `<div class="row">` and `<div class="col-md-6 my-3">`. See my fiddle link.

Comment: i mean I want to used the full-width of the card.. it appears that the textbox has a   maximum width and so I try to change my included file. Instead of using my downloaded file in nuget, I used the link of bootstrap online and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define parent div with full with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 my-6">
                            <div class="card card-outline-secondary">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <form class="form" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label form-control-label">First Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Last name</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Middle name</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Name Extension</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Date of Birth</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="date" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Gender</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label"></label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Cancel">
                                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div><!-- card body -->
                            </div> <!-- card-outline -->
                        </div>
                    </div>         
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm running this in asp.net mvc. and it appears the textbox has a max-width.  what do you mean of div with full-width?

Comment: Please look your second line in which you have defined col-md-6 my-3 instead of col-md-12 my-6 that's why it will not appear into full screen

Comment: I'd fixed it now, I tried to used the link online instead of the local file I downloaded in Nuget in visual studio. It appears that the one included in the code is bootstrap.css when it should be bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```
input, select, textarea {max-width: 100% !important;}
```